# How can I correctly insert a data into vec.get(0) without main function?

Tags: java, vector

```
class Instruction{
  Buffer buf = new Buffer();
  Vector<Buffer> vec = new Vector<Buffer>();
  vec.add(buf);  <--error
  ...
}

class Buffer{
  String name = new String( "Buffer-" );
  Vector<String> word = new Vector<String>();
  public Buffer(){
    name = new String( "Buffer-" );
    word = new Vector<String>();
  } // public
}
```

`error: <identifier> expected`

I want to insert `buf` into `vec.get(0);`

However, It has a problem.

How can I fixed it ?

I don't know what's going on. This shouldn't be wrong.

Comment: Put it in the constructor, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, obviously the answer is that the `add` function has to be called from a method, probably the constructor:

```
class Instruction {
  Buffer buf = new Buffer();
  Vector<Buffer> vec = new Vector<Buffer>();
  public Instruction() {
    vec.add(buf);
  }
}
```

But there's also a fun way that doesn't use the constructor:

```
class Instruction {
  Buffer buf = new Buffer();
  Vector<Buffer> vec = new Vector<Buffer>() {{
    add(buf);
  }};
}
```

This is "double brace initialization" and is slightly abusive of Java syntax but does work. The outer set of braces introduce an anonymous subclass of `Vector<Buffer>`. The inner braces are an initialization block for that subclass.

You could also initialize `vec` with another collection you create just for the purpose:

```
class Instruction {
  Buffer buf = new Buffer();
  Vector<Buffer> vec = new Vector<Buffer>(Collections.singleton(buf));
}
```

Comment: If I also want to ```vec.set()```, how can I create another constructor ?

Comment: `vec.set` with what? Maybe that's another question. :-)

Comment: It's not a good idea to use double brace initializers because they create an extra class. It's probably more concise to just use a for loop like `for (Buffer b : new Buffer[]{buf1, buf2, ...}) vec.add(b);`

Comment: Are you paying per class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you must put `vec.add()` into a method. Like someone commented you can put this in a constructor.

The error `identifier expected` is not a terribly helpful one in this context, but it refers to the fact that method calls made outside of a method can only be used to initialize a variable. Thus it expects a variable to be set equal to whatever the method returns and the identifier refers to the name that identifies that variable.

In order for your program to run it needs some sort of main method. There are some "exceptions" to this (spring boot comes to mind), but in these cases the main method is hidden instead of missing. The main method is necessary, otherwise Java would not know where to start executing code. So if there is no main, you have something more like a library than a program, which needs a program to call its methods in order to do anything. I hope this helps.